# I don't understand the many concepts of openlayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I am not a country in English, so the grammar may be wrong. Please understand.
I'd appreciate it if you could just give me an example.

```
1) ol.source : I'm curious about the role of the source.

2) ol.feature : I wonder what is "feature"..

3) layer.getSource().clear() : Is this a function that exists in the
ol library?
```

By the way, I have a distance measurement code, the
code is very simple, but I don't know how it works.

`Layer.getSource().start`  - what is "start" function..?

Is "start" in the openlayers library? Or is it made and used by someone?

I think "source" has various functions..

```
var Btn = document.getElementById('button');
function distance() {
    Layer.getSource().start({
        map : map,
        type : 'LineString'
    });
}
Btn.addEventListener('click', distance);
```

There is no error, but is there a way to see the inside of the "start"?
I couldn't find it through search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see the OpenLayers-functions, check out the [official API](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/index.html).

To get started with OpenLayers, you can find the [basic concepts and good tutorials here.](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/tutorials/)

1.) An `ol.source` is a container of features (see below) and generally is the data-source of a. `ol.layer`. The layers are what you see on the map. Most maps have at least one BaseLayer and some other layers. Think about a map with the streets as a BaseLayer (background) and icons of restaurants and bars as another layer (for instance an `ol.layer.vector`).

2.) A `feature` is a geographic object. It has a geometry (e.g. point, line, polygon), properties (e.g. name, amount, opening hours), and a style. In the example above, a restaurant can be a feature with a point-geometry, a name and opening hours as properties and an `Icon` as style.

3.) `layer.getSource().clear()` is indeed an ol function, it deletes the contents of a source, for instance a `vectorSource`: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_Vector-VectorSource.html#clear

Your `start` -method is not an official OpenLayers method, it looks homemade.